# asp.net mvc recaptcha 1.6 The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, https, certificate, recaptcha

Impossible to host website with asp.net mvc recaptcha 1.6 .
If you deploy a website in an SLL, the control generate an error :
The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
How to correct this error

Answer (score 0):

Decompile the project Recaptcha.Web.dll with 'Telerik Just Decompile' (it's free)

And modify 2 lines in RecaptchaVerificationHelper class :

In the method VerifyRecaptchaResponse the code must be :

```
uri = (this.UseSsl ? new Uri("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify", 
      UriKind.Absolute) : new Uri("http://api-verify.recaptcha.net/verify", 
      UriKind.Absolute));
```

In the method VerifyRecaptchaResponseTaskAsync the code must be :

```
uri = (this.UseSsl ? new Uri("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify", 
      UriKind.Absolute) : new Uri("http://api-verify.recaptcha.net/verify", 
      UriKind.Absolute));
```